# Visual Studio Project Wizard fails

Tags: visual-studio, objectarx

The Autodesk ObjectARX project wizards fail to create projects in visual studio professional. I only see in the status bar at the bottom that it has failed. How can I tell what's wrong?
I've checked the visual studio logs (using devenv.exe /log) with nothing reported. And I don't see any other logs. What else can I do?

I should add that there should be a ui, but nothing appears. It fails right away.

Comment: Haven't used the wizard you're talking about, but are you running VS as Administrator?

Comment: Yes, I'm running VS as admin.

Answer (score 1):

- Uninstall the wizard.
- Right click on wizard setup file
- Troubleshoot compatibility and follow steps to install
- Try, it works

Answer (score 0):

You should put the ObjectARX folders (inc, lib or so) to "C:\ObjectARX".
Another place is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because on wizard 2018 installation leave field "Registered Developer Symbol" empty. Then on using wizard you can change this symbol to any other.

Other name for ObjectARX directory allow successfully install wizard 2018  but then will be problem in project settings where this path hardcoded as c:\ObjectARX. So better use c:\ObjectARX.